# Failed to import javax.transaction.UserTransaction

Tags: eclipse, transactions, import, jta

I created a new JPA project where i need to use `javax.transaction.UserTransaction`. While I can import `javax.naming.*`, `javax.persistence.*`, I cannot import `javax.transaction.UserTransaction`: the message received is the classic `"The import javax.transaction.UserTransaction cannot be resolved"`.
I'm using as jdk.1.7.0_03 and I'm from Eclipse Indigo.

Where am I wrong? Thanks,
Andrea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my issue simply creating a Java Project for ProjectA with the javax.transaction.jar in the build path.

Comment: I used this solution successfully. That leads me to a question. Why is this necessary although its existing in %JBOSS_HOME%/modules/system/layers/base/javax/transaction/api/main/jboss-transaction-api_1.3_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar for server version wildfly-18.0.0.Final? Shouldn't it compile with (unsuccessfull in my case) pom.xml?

   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.3_spec</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>

Answer (score 1):

Importing `javax.transaction.UserTransaction` fails because you do not have library that contains it in your project. You need JTA API/implementation. Typically same implementation as in target the application server is used.

Comment: Thanks, Mikko. Ok, I understand. Let me add some details: what I need is that the project I mentioned above (let's call it ProjectA) could be imported by a web project (with Glassfish, let's call it ProjectB). So I need to use JTA, but not directly (the web project B uses it throught the ProjectA). This doesn't allow me to add the transactions, so how can my web app use them?